# Как подсчитать количество написанного кода в репозитории по авторам?

Tags: git, git-log

Задача узнать, кто из авторов сколько кода написал. Я знаю, что это необъективная информация для подсчета вклада в проект, но все же хоть какая-то статистика. Если знаете какие-то решения, актуальные на данный момент - прошу поделиться.

Пробовал пользоваться [вот этим пакетом](https://github.com/caelum/git-reports), но он устарел, т.к. был написан более семи лет назад. Более новых google не выдал.

Есть команда `git log --numstat`, но она выдает разрозненные данные по коммитам и ей невозможно воспользоваться для данных целей. Или я все же что-то пропустил?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Есть команда `git log --numstat`, но она выдает разрозненные данные по коммитам и ей невозможно воспользоваться для данных целей. Или я все же что-то пропустил?

так на основании выдаваемой информации можно подсчитать, сколько строк добавил и сколько удалил (именно такие цифры выдаёт `git log --numstat`) каждый автор.

примерно вот так (это я быстренько «набросал», можно и улучшить и оптимизировать):

```
$ git log --pretty=format:==%an --numstat | \
 sed -r '/==.*/{s/^==//;h;D};/^$/D;s/-/0/g;s/\t[^\t]+$//;G;s/(.*)\n(.*)/\2\t\1/' \
 | awk -F '\t' '{add[$1]+=$2;del[$1]+=$3} END {for (i in add) {print i,add[i],del[i]}}'
```

для упомянутого вами проекта она выдаёт:

```
Caue Guerra 361 168
Pedro Matiello 729 238
```

для проекта https://github.com/processone/ejabberd вот такую статистику выдаёт:

```
Alexey Shchepin 121555 48334
Andreas Köhler 429 335
Antonio Murdaca 63 10
Anton Ryzhov 0 1
Arno B 22 5
Badlop 310727 228783
Balázs Galambosi 2 2
Ben Langfeld 87 110
bLaDe 1 1
Christian Dröge 17 12
Christopher A. Stelma 1 1
Christophe Romain 42755 54608
Christopher tofu Zorn 128 96
colm 8 3
Cor Cornelisse 2 2
Denis Kurochkin 600 2
ekhramtsov 44 4
Elias Rohrer 24 87
Emilio Bustos 82 52
Evgeniy Khramtsov 229257 210283
Evgeny Khramtsov 0 15
Feotov Daniil 67 6
Geoff Cant 279 163
GreenLunar 66 98
Gu Feng 7 3
HAMANO Tsukasa 390 320
Holger Wei 2 0
Holger Weiss 5665 3161
iulianlaz 13 1
jabber 5 0
Jamie Nguyen 401 532
Janusz Dziemidowicz 129 41
Jerome Sautret 1300 199
Jérôme Sautret 1465 1011
Johan Oudinet 16 12
Jonas Ådahl 7 1
jpegger 1 1
Juan Pablo Carlino 2 2
Leif Bredgaard Honore 2 2
liudan 6 4
Marek Foss 12 5
Martin Langhoff 81 7
Mathias Ertl 33 31
Matthias Rieber 22 6
Matwey V. Kornilov 7 13
Maxim Ignatenko 857 567
Mickael Remond 1458 1118
Mickaël Rémond 394 115
Mickaël Rémond 44205 25665
Mikhail-D 1783 0
mrjameshamilton 1 1
Nathan Bruning 13 11
Nikolaus Polak 17 20
Nycholas de Oliveira e Oliveira 3 1
Otavio Fernandes 71 60
oxpa 4 2
Pablo Polvorin 556 152
Paul Donohue 8 4
Paweł Chmielowski 3305 3548
Peter Lemenkov 11 2
Quan Zhuo 4 4
Radosław Szymczyszyn 51 74
Rahul Gautam 9 9
Remco Wendt 8 0
Sergey Abramyan 542 15
Shelley Shyan 91 104
Sonny Scroggin 167 135
Stephen Röttger 43 36
Steven Lehrburger 2 4
stewart 1 1
Taufan Aditya 5 8
thierry 2 0
tjeerd 4 0
tmallard 6553 1300
Tsukasa Hamano 6 12
Tuncer Ayaz 2 2
vesvalo 19 7
Victor Rodrigues 74 73
W. Andrew Loe III 1 0
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Правда, отрабатывает довольно долго на реальных проектах. Пишу это сообщение, а результата все нет ))) Хотя на более мелком тестовом проекте быстро посчитало. О, вот и результат! )))