# Интересует плагин статистики

Tags: git, github

Интересует плагин для github'a который собирал бы информацию, по одному или нескольким репозиториям. Информацию такого рода - кто сколько строк кода написал, временные рамки. Ну и чтобы собирал сколько правок на текущую ветку.

Comment: установить плагин на сервер github вряд ли получится. может быть, [«подручными» средствами](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/501928/178576) — будет более вероятно?

Comment: я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что «[вопросы о том, где найти программы, библиотеки, учебники по программированию и администрированию — не стоит задавать](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin прочитал критерии, данный вопрос не удовлетворяет их. тем более как оказалось надо искать не плагин а писать команду.

Comment: да, формулировка вопроса выглядит «не очень». как автор вопроса, вы можете его удалить. если движок не позволит этого сделать (из-за «плюса»), можно воспользоваться ссылкой «тревога» ниже вопроса и изложить модераторам причину, почему вопрос следует удалить.