# Можно ли создать единый отчет из коммитов?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

Есть несколько разработчиков, каждый работает над своим проектом. Мне нужно иметь данные о продуктивности разработчиков, то есть собрать отчет о проделанной работе на основе коммитов (желательно на основе коммитов на GitHub, bitbucket, но это не критично). Так же желательно создавать отчеты о продуктивности (количество коммитов в день/неделю/месяц). Есть ли какие то готовые решения для этого, или как можно организовать все это дело ? Заранее спасибо.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/501896/178576

Answer (score 2):

Честно говоря, погуглив - на нашел толкового решения по вашему вопросу, но ощущение что у вас Ошибка молотка.

[Что такое «Ошибка молотка» или «Ошибка XY»?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/709/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-xy)

Вы хотите понять, насколько эффективен конкретный разработчик и сравнивать их между собой?
 Смотрите на результаты разработки, а не на колличество написанных строк кода или коммитов.
В процессе любой  разработки необходимо иметь стадию тестирования продукта, собственно на этой стадии по количеству багов, скорости их фикса, и скорости реализации фич. Это - лично мой пример показателей для определения качества работы девелопера.
Также, очень важно иметь баг-трекер\таск-трекер, который активно ведут тестировщики, девелоперы, PM-ы и т.д. Следить за процессом реализации фич, скоростью фикса багов(срочные и не срочные баги в данной ситуации имеют разное влияние на "оценку" разработчика).

Если вы считаете, что колличество коммитов/строк кода влияет на качество разработки - поработайте с индусами. Коммитов туча, кода много - результативность крайне мала.
**UPD**

Нашел несколько полезных штук, но сам их не проверял -
 
[Тык](https://github.com/apis/gitstatistics)
 
[И тут](https://www.openhub.net/)
 
[И ещё здесь](http://gitstats.sourceforge.net/)
**UPD-2**
Из комментария к моему ответу, также следует дополнить ответ:
Людям свойственно приспосабливаться к трудностям и вкусностям. Есть Вася, который имеет 10 коммитов в день, но колличество багов на квадратный миллиметр строчки кода у него невероятное.
И есть Петя, который коммитит раз в день-два, но у Пети багов почти нет, а если находятся - то он их быстро фиксит.
Задайте себе вопрос, кто более эффективен? Принесет ли вам пользу ваша метрика?

Comment: Добавлю, что к любым искусственным показателям эффективности люди приспосабливаются, после чего значения показателей становятся высокими, а реальная польза — низкой.